# Telegram webhook polls old ip after webhook change

Tags: python, telegram, webhooks

Working with core-telegram and python.
Recently changed my vps from 5.252.118.129 to another ip addr (79.137.194.182).
After this, telegram still trying to access old IP (/getWebhookInfo)
[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gNBa.png)

I have domain - https://t1mqa.ru , i used
`curl https://api.telegram.org/bot{KEY}/setWebhook?url=https://t1mqa.ru/api/telegramHook`

Now my ip and dns'es are 79.137.194.182, what to do, and how can i change this IP in telegram request? (There's no way to link https://79.137.194.182/endpoint cause certs are using t1mqa.ru domain)